# Spring STS and code completion from the view (JSP or JSF) pages

Tags: spring, jsf-2, cdi, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, jboss-tools

Working with JBoss Tools and CDI I very much liked the fact that when I was editing a JSF page I had access to the CDI beans and autocomplete was very helpful.

Now with Spring MVC and STS I provide values to the view pages with `model.addAttribute` however the page editor has very limited autocomplete capabilities.

Is there another programming way to make the editor more aware of my beans while editing a JSF page? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think so.  STS would have to know that "model" was an instance of XYZ, but "model" can be set to anything at any time.

Comment: yes addAttribute  is so ugly, the main problem of spring is lack of useful binding method ,However in big companies it is not so bad due to html developers don't know about java code , we use RequestParam instead of binding ,But even your are developing yourself I recommend use Wicket on view layer by using  AT SpringBean